# Pokemon lost in Gym

Tags: pokemon-go

I put my Pokemon in a gym. Then, the gym was taken and held by several different teams, but I did not get my Pokemon back. It is still showing it's assigned to the gym. What can I do to get it back? It was my highest CP Pokemon.

Comment: Could you attach some screenshots to show what you are experiencing?

Comment: Have you tried to retake the gym? That might help? Also do you keep getting the Defender badge bonus for it every 21 hours? If so, this bug might even be more beneficial for you :-) If not just wait another day and if it's still not back maybe send a ticket to Niantic but it might take a long time before they respond though...

Comment: @Mr.Meeseeks I want 2 strokes off my game

Comment: @Insane Caaaaaaaaaan do! xD

Answer (score 1):

Just wait. It will take a little while for the game to check Gym status and establish that your Pokémon was defeated and return it to you.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, gyms tend to update the Pokemon inside of them to be returned every 5 to 15 or so minutes, regardless of how many times it was recaptured. As @NiettheDarkAbsol said, wait a little bit of time then check back.